# Postgresql format function of boolean values cast to jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

When I try to format() a postgresql boolean value and cast the value to a jsonb object, PostgreSQL raises an exception:

```
# select format('%s', true)::jsonb;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "t" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: t
```

I am fairly sure that formatting a boolean value gives either t or f rather than the full word, which is what json expects it to be.

There already is a solution to this by using the case statement

```
 select format('%s', case when true then 'true' else 'false' end)::jsonb;
 format 
--------
  true
(1 row)
```

However, while this may seem fine for the trivial case above, when it's used in functions and anything more complicated it looks quite out of place. Is there a neater solution to this?

The context is that I have a function returning a hash of keys mapping to boolean flags, which are decided by functions. A sample of what one function could look like is

```
return format( '{
        "is_valid" : %s,
        "is_authorized" : %s,
        "is_not_delegated" : %s,
        }',
        is_valid(function_argument),
        is_authorized(function_argument),
        not is_delegated(function_argument)
 )::jsonb;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    row_to_json(q)
from (
    select 
        true is_valid,
        false is_authorized
) q
```

Comment: Please consider adding some detail to your answer.

Comment: this answer is not using the format function

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast from boolean to text like as my_column::text

```
select format('{"level":%s,"cluster":%s}', rl.level, rl.cluster::text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
select format('%s', true::text)::jsonb;
```